# Xampp: Open Apache and MySQL, then Webbrowser

Tags: apache, batch-file, xampp

I need one .bat-file which...

1. start Xampp Apache
2. start Xampp MySQL-Server
3. Wait until step 1 and 2 are finished
4. Open Webbrowser and navigate to *localhost*

I tryed to combine the .bat-files from the xampp-folder, but it's stopping at *Apache 2 is starting ...*

Here the file:

```
@echo off
cd /D %~dp0
echo Please close this command only for Shutdown
echo Apache 2 is starting ...

apache\bin\httpd.exe

cd /D %~dp0
echo Please dont close Window while MySQL is running
echo MySQL is trying to start
echo Please wait  ...
echo MySQL is starting with mysql\bin\my.ini (console)

mysql\bin\mysqld --defaults-file=mysql\bin\my.ini --standalone --console



"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
sleep1
start "Localhost" "http://localhost"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert for batch files but this is an example that I wrote for myself. It launches the xampp control-panel ( that can be configured to auto start the apache and mysql modules ), browser and editor ( Firefox and Notepad++ for example ). If the xampp is already started those same programs will be closed.

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq xampp-control.exe" | findstr /I "xampp-control.exe" && (
    taskkill /IM firefox.exe
    taskkill /IM notepad++.exe
    cd "C:\xampp"
    call apache_stop.bat
    call mysql_stop.bat
    taskkill /f /IM xampp-control.exe
) || (
    start C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe
    cd "C:\Program Files\Notepad++"
    start notepad++.exe
    cd "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox"
    start firefox.exe http://localhost/
)
exit
```

Answer (score -2):

start http://localhost/ will take you automatically to browser, But I don't think so you can run apache and mysql